# Grabbing a simple string from the first tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm honestly finding `BeautifulSoup` too difficult, the documentation doesn't explain the basics I'm looking for.

I am trying to return the string inside a tag that has an attribute:

```
<span class="on">6220</span>
```

But running this:

```
def fetch_online():
    users = page('span', {'class' : 'on'})
    return str(users)
```

Gives me `[<span class="on">6220</span>]`. So I figured I'm doing it all wrong, what is the way to just get a simple string out of a tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
html = # your HTML source goes here
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
x = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'on'})
print x.text
print x.string
print x.contents[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's true that BeautifulSoup is not so easy to understand but it can be sooo useful sometimes ;)

So, to re-take FlopCoder exemple and explain it a little bit more :

```
html = # HTML Code #maybe parsed from a website
soup = BeautifulSoup(html) #you create a soup object with your html code
x = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'on'}) #Search for the first span balise in the code, whith class : on
print x.text #Find the found balise, .text mean only the text inside the <>text</>
```

In the case you have more than one  to find you need to do :

```
x = soup.findAll('span', {'class' : 'on'})
for span in x:
    print span.text
```

This last exemple use findAll. It creates a list with all the span balises with Class:On in the code. So then you can run a for.

your_object.text --> return the text

your_object.a --> return the link (and so on ...)

Hope it can help a little bit !

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
return str(users)
```

with

```
return users[0].string
```

or

```
return users[0].contents
```

The `page('span ...` call is actually shorthand notation for calling the `find_all()` function, which returns a list. So you first index into that list, get the tag, then get its `contents`. Running the Python `str()` function on it is going to give you the whole thing - you want the BeautifulSoup function for getting the string of a tag.